# What is the use of NOT CONNECTED pin in 741 opamp?

Tags: integrated-circuit, pins

When I attended a viva about the IC Applications, I was asked **What is the use of NC pin in 741 opamp?** so I answered as *it just indicates no need of any connection to that pin* in return I was asked *then why this pin is placed?* Unfortunately I didn't answer.

I researched about it and found that **it is filler space** from this [article](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/NC-not-connected-terminal-of-a-chip).

Is there anything else I didn't reached in this case?
and What is **Filler space**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason for no connect pins is that the manufacturers use [standard ic packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrated_circuit_packaging_types).

The package for a given device must have (clearly) at least the number of pins required to bring out all functional pins; in the case of the 741 (and countless other devices) the number of pins required for functionality is less than the number of pins on the package.

Those pins that are not required for functionality are still required for the standard package and are simply not connected to anything.

On complex devices with hundreds (or more) pins, it is not uncommon to see *numerous* NC pins.

Updated for a comment by Spehro: I should have noted this, especially as I have recently been using a [device](http://www.linear.com/product/LT3752) that has just such an arrangement:

> The LT3752/LT3752-1 are available in a 38-lead plastic TSSOP  package  with  missing  pins  for  high  voltage spacings.

Comment: Yes!, You're right, moreover *DIP chips are not made with an odd number of pins.*

Comment: There are many packages (not DIPs perhaps) that *do* have an odd number of pins (particularly those with an exposed pad on the underside).

Comment: Yep, I have never seen a DIP package with a thermal pad or an odd number of pins. If you can extend the set to SIL packages you can get odd pins though.

Comment: @VladimirCravero or just a metal can uA741

Comment: @Asmyldof yep, well I think that the fancy round thingies are even more difficult to be added in the DI{P|L} family

Comment: @PeterSmith I think he means an "odd" number in the sense of an unusual, nonstandard number; not in the sense of a number that isn't divisible by 2.

Comment: There are DIP packages with [*missing*](http://www.sharpsma.com/download/pr39mf2-epdf) pins (typically for reasons of clearance/creepage) and likely some with pins tied together externally as one (but that fan out into individual through-hole  (typically for reasons of power dissipation or current carrying), but convention is to number as if the pins were standard.

Comment: @PeterSmith, they do make DIP ICs with odd numbers of pins these days but not in the time the 741 was designed. The DIP packages back then were very few and very simple. The 741 was originally available in a 'top-hat' metal can and that IFIRC lacked the n.c. pin.

Comment: Sometimes NC pins have actual thermal significance; some stepper motor chips have pins that are strictly "radiator pins" for binding them thermally with radiators. Though often these are  GND instead of NC.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add to the previous answers that there are actually two distinct cases.

1) Extra pin in package not physically connected to the die. It is okay to connect other things to this pin (I have done this on a super tight board because it helped the routing).

2) The pin is used during the manufacturing process to test/trim something. This is much less common. In this case the pin *must* float as directed by the datasheet for proper operation.

Comment: Amazing.. NC pin has helped you in *routing* , can i know some more details about this...

Comment: The board was 1 by 5 cm. the ic was up against the edge of the board so the traces had to leave along the inside of the chip. There was a via I couldn't move blocking one of the pins on the inside. So I jogged through the neighboring NC pin and then out. Pretty specific scenario but it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There is another reason for NC pins. Sometimes those pins are used by the manufacturer to put the IC in test mode during manufacturing validation tests.

For example, See [Altera's "MAX® V Device Family Pin Connection Guidelines"<sup>PDF</sup>](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/dp/max-v/pcg-01012.pdf).
In that document it says of `NC` pins:

> Do not connect these pins to any signal. These pins must be left unconnected.

which would not matter if the pins were *truely* unwired. Usually the manufacturers, for fear of reverse-engineering, don't disclose the functionality of those pins.

Comment: Can you give a specific example?

Comment: Sure. For example, you can take a look at the datasheet of TI DSP TMS320C6415. You will see that there are several pins marked RSV (reserved). Some of those pins MUST be connected to Vdd for proper operation, some others MUST be left unconnected. The reason for that is that some of them are for test, and if you don't put the values they ask for, your device can enter test mode and behave funny. Usually the manufacturers, for fear of reverse-engineering, don't disclose the functionality of those pins.

Comment: @BrockAdams then maybe you want to take a look at this datasheet of the Max V from Altera. https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/dp/max-v/pcg-01012.pdf - Regarding the NC pins it says: Do not connect these pins to any signal. These pins must be left unconnected.

Comment: The problem, Brock, is that manufacturers don't like to talk about this and in many cases you can't really know if an NC pin is really not connected to the die, or is a test pin, or a disabled feature, or a future expansion. You can only suspect, specially if you are ordered to leave them unconnected or to connect them to a specific gnd or voltage.